# XSLT match based on concatenating two node values

Tags: xslt

If I have xml that looks like this

```
<Msg>
    <Payload role="s">
       <row>
         <venue>XDM</venue>
         <account>60190</account>
       </row>
    </Payload>
    <Payload role="c" id="atom1">
      <ResultSet>
         <Row>
            <U_LegAcc>XDM60190</U_LegAcc>
            <U_AccCod>SYS00000000508</U_AccCod>
         </Row>
      </ResultSet>
    </Payload>
</Msg>
```

I need to get the U_AccCod node value based on the U_LegAcc which is matched to the concatenated value of venue (XDM) & account (61090) i.e. XDM61090

How can I get xml that looks like this.

```
<Msg>
  <Payload>
   <row>
     <venue>XDM</venue>
     <account>60190</account>
     <U_AccCod>SYS00000000508</U_AccCod>
   </row>
 </Payload>
</Msg>
```

I have tried simplifying it and removing the concatenation just to get a start but I can't even get that to work, i.e. `<account>` and `<U_AccCod>` are the same. I have tried using a key but I am not getting any output

```
<xsl:key name="sapaccount" match="ResultSet" use="U_LegAcc" />

<xsl:template match="Row" mode="name">
   <xsl:value-of select="U_AccCod" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/account">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sapaccount', .)" mode="name" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the part of your XSL which is emitting the `row` element from the same element in the input:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:copy-of select="venue"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="account"/>
        <U_AccCod>
            <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Msg/Payload/ResultSet/Row/U_AccCod[../U_LegAcc=concat($this/venue,$this/account)]"/>
        </U_AccCod>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested, may need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for that....had some name space issues but finally got it working with your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no reason why you can't continue to use the key here. They are generally more efficient to use to look up elements. The problem with your current key is that is not quite correct. You are currently looking for `ResultSet` elements by means of the `U_LegAcc` value, but `U_LegAcc` is not a direct child of `ResultSet`, but of `Row`, so you probably want to define your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="sapaccount" match="ResultSet/Row" use="U_LegAcc" />
```

Or maybe just this, if `Row` elements can only occur in one place

```
<xsl:key name="sapaccount" match="Row" use="U_LegAcc" />
```

Then, to look up the value, if positioned on a `account` element, you would do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('sapaccount', concat(preceding-sibling::venue, .))" />
```

Or better still, have a template to match the `row` element, and then you can do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('sapaccount', concat(venue, account))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="sapaccount" match="Row" use="U_LegAcc"/>

   <xsl:template match="Payload[@role='s']">
      <Payload>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Payload>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Payload[@role='c']"/>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <row>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sapaccount', concat(venue, account))/U_AccCod"/>
      </row>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<Msg>
   <Payload>
      <row>
         <venue>XDM</venue>
         <account>60190</account>
         <U_AccCod>SYS00000000508</U_AccCod>
      </row>
   </Payload>
</Msg>
```